# How do I delete all documents not in a collection?

Tags: pouchdb

I'm just getting started with pouchdb, and I'm running into an issue.

I have a collection of documents, from a source other than the pouchdb database. They have _id's, but they don't have _rev's.

What I want to do is to:

1. Any documents that exist in the collection and do not exist in the database should be added to the database
2. Any documents that exist in the collection and do exist in the database should have their values in the database updated to those of the document in the collection
3. Any documents that exist in the database and do not exist in the collection should be deleted from the database.

The obvious handling for the first two is to loop through the collection and for each document determine if it exists in the database, and ff it does, set the _rev. Then put the document.

The "obvious" handling for the third would be to find every document in the database that did not have an _id that matched any of the _id's in the collection.

But I'm not sure how to do that. What I'm looking for is something like a "NOT IN", but I'm not finding it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working for me. The trick is to use the "$nin" operator.

Suggestions for improvements?

```
const replaceAllFoos = async (foos: [Foo]) => {

    foos.forEach(foo => {
        foo._id = buildId(foo);
        foo.collectiontype = "foo";
    });

    const ids = foos.map(foo => foo._id);

    await getDb(async db => {
        for await (const foo of foos) {
            try {
                const existing = await db.get(foo._id!);
                foo._rev = existing._rev;
            } catch (err) {
                if (err.status !== 404) {
                    throw err;
                }
            }

            await db.put(foo);
        }

        let extras = await db.find({
            selector: {
                "$and": [
                    {"collectiontype": {"$eq": "foo" }},
                    {"_id": {"$nin": ids}}
                ]
            }
        });

        for await (const extra of extras.docs) {
            await db.remove(extra)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to replicate to another database with a filter that picks up everything you do want while not picking up anything you don't want.

Once you have verified that you have neither undesirables nor missing items, you can delete the original database and replicate back again.